# snipe-avy - combine evil-snipe with avy, highlighting of the selected chars to jump to avy-style

Tags: evil, avy

This is a bit advanced ask, but maybe it's possible. Assuming there are multiple same characters on the same line selected by `evil-snipe` it would be awesome if one could navigate to other characters by mark selection similar to avy, that is:
[image]

After pressing `ig` I want to be able to jump to the second `ig` not only by repeat command, but I would like to actually have some letter above these two characters, for example `a`, so I could jump to this position by pressing some combination, for example `a`.

The `avy` like suggestion should pop up immediately after pressing the first character.

I found the thread https://github.com/hlissner/evil-snipe/issues/25 which seems to mention `avy-snipe`, but I think they talk about something different.
I know this is a bit of effort, especially to have some avy chars pop up above the letters in order to be selected as the candidates, but I would be curious on whether it's feasible in not too much time or maybe even proposing a solution.

The reason I am asking is that I would like to be able to jump and iterate evil-snipe style, but in case there is a lot of repeated sequences also being able to press `C-...` to jump to the desired position. I am using doom-emacs on Mac OS.

Comment: If you are limiting evil-snipe to the same line, why not just press repeat once or twice to reach your destination?  Do you often have more than 3 occurrences of the same two-character combination on a line?

Comment: When you use evil-snipe two characters, you have to put in the second character and then press repeat, I see this proposal as a strict improvement over current snipe functionality.
Even with 3 occurences this type of function would be quite convenient over time.

Comment: Actually I discovered the `closure` command which in principle does what I want `evil-snipe-parent-transient-map`. The problem there is it doesn't run parallel to the standard selection procedure and the suggestions are not depicted above the letters.